# Insert a div before the first h2 on a page

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to insert using Vanilla Javascript to insert a node before a H2 tag.  I thought insertBefore was what I want but I may be wrong.

```
            const nodes = document.getElementsByTagName("h2");
            divMove = document.createElement("div");
            divMove.className = "contents";
            nodes[0].insertBefore(divMove, nodes[0]);
```

What javascript command should I use to insert a div before the first h2 on a page.  Any help is appreciated.  Its to occur on multiple pages where there h2 id won't be the same.

Comment: should be something like `nodes[0].parentElement.insertBefore(divMove, nodes[0]);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is close. The missing bit is that [`Node.insertBefore()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/insertBefore) is a method that needs to be called on the *parent node* of the target:

> The `insertBefore()` method of the [`Node`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node) interface inserts a node before a *reference node* as a child of a specified *parent node*.

```js
const nodes = document.getElementsByTagName("h2");
divMove = document.createElement("div");
divMove.textContent = "div text";
nodes[0].parentNode.insertBefore(divMove, nodes[0]);
//      ^^^^^^^^^^^
```

```html
<div>
  <h2>First</h2>
  <h2>Second</h2>
<div>
```

Comment: Thank you, this was the solution I used, it didn't occur to me to use parentNode.  All works and thanks for everyone's time and solutions.

Answer (score 0):

You can shorten the exercise by using `element.insertAdjacentHTML()`:

```js
document.querySelector("h2").insertAdjacentHTML("beforebegin",`<div class="contents">This is the inserted div.</div>`);
```

```html
<H2>My heading</H2>
<H2>Another heading</H2>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`Element#before`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/before) instead, which is more convenient and intuitive. This method directly inserts nodes before the specified element; there is no need to consider the parent at all.

```js
const div = document.createElement('div');
div.className = 'contents';
div.textContent = 'div text';
document.querySelector('h2').before(div);
```

```html
<h2>h2 title</h2>
<h3>h3 title</h3>
<h2>another h2 title</h2>
```